# Rabbitmq - minimum system requirements

Tags: rabbitmq

How to estimate resources (cpu, memory, for rabbitmq? On the manufacturer's website I found the short information https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [PerfTest](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html#load-testing) to simulate your expected and potential future workloads.